# Does Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit have graphic user interface?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, vagrant

I am new to Virtualbox and Vagrant.

I followed Vagrant Get Started Guide, and have a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html

However, there's no graphical user interface (only a terminal).

Could anyone point me a box with a GUI?

Comment: I was asking myself the same thing. What really confused me is that the `hashicorp/precise32` box does not explicitly say whether it's the desktop or server variant. It just says "A standard Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit box", but "standard" in my world would be "desktop", and there are LTS versions of both desktop and server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, no. Server distros don't have a GUI, but you can easily add one using apt-get.

People commonly use Gnome, XFCE etc. A quick search will get you what you need, depending on which Desktop Environment (DE) you're looking for.

XFCE is great and lightweight. If you're running a server system, you might want that to keep memory free for other applications.

Installing XFCE

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Installing Gnome

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After installing the desktop, you'll also want to install GDM which will let you boot directly into a graphical environment. (or lightDM)

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

or:
    sudo apt-get install lightdm

Once done, you'll want to configure it.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: Thanks, BenK... running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` causes `add-apt-repository: command not found`.  Any idea on solving the problem?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties` solves that problem

Comment: Note that `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` will install Xubuntu themes, applications, etc. while `apt-get install xfce4` just installs XFCE. The same goes for LXDE.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you - it didn't for me - take gdm out of the equation. The only thing you need is 1. `sudo apt-get install xfce4` and then 2. `sudo startxfce4&`. That's it.

Comment: Don't forget to configure the GUI in vagrant. Example for vagrant + virtualbox:                                    `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v| v.gui = true end`

Comment: @Air read somewhere that `startxfce4` should be ran from the `vagrant` user and not root. Maybe for security? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024671/288644

Comment: @BenK How do you know it's a "server distro"? The OP just mentioned LTS, but there are LTS versions of both desktop and server.